# Django - How to query the Django Comments Framework

Tags: python, django, django-comments

I'm using the Django Comments Framework.

I need to query all the comments of a certain Content Type. How can I do that?

In the view I'm doing this query:

```
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment

comments = Comment.objects.all().order_by('-submit_date')
```

Now, on the view how can I query the related object information(certain Content Type)?

Any clues?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
comentarios = Comment.objects.filter(content_type=11).order_by('-submit_date')
```

Template:

```
{{ item.content_object }}
```